# Configure local jar in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

In my maven project I need to use some local `jar` libraries as a dependency.

I'm trying to use this method to configure them in `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>projectName.local</id>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- other dependencies... -->
</dependencies>
```

I defined a local repository that points to a `libs` folder into the project root. Then I placed the `jar`s in this folder:

```
/libs/org/myproject/ProjectName/1.0/ProjectName-1.0.jar
```

But, building the project I'm getting this warning:

```
The POM for org.myproject:ProjectName:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

And this build failure result:

```
Failed to execute goal on project my_project: Could not resolve dependencies for project *** : The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.myproject:ProjectName:jar:1.0: Failure to find org.myproject:ProjectName:jar:1.0 in file://C:\Users\David\Documents\NetBeansProjects\my_project/libs was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of projectName.local has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Start to to use a repository manager upload the jar their and it's done ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think just copying the jar file will not solve your problem. You will need to install the dependency using Maven itself in that repository using a command like this one:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file  -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar \
                -DgroupId=your.groupId \
                -DartifactId=your-artifactId \
                -Dversion=version \
                -Dpackaging=jar \
                -DlocalRepositoryPath=path-to-specific-local-repo
```

`path-to-specific-local-repo` should be the path to your local repository (`file://${project.basedir}/libs`).

Comment: I'm following these tutorials: http://doduck.com/adding-local-jar-in-maven-local-repository/ and http://roufid.com/3-ways-to-add-local-jar-to-maven-project/ (3rd method) and they don't mention this

Comment: @davioooh how are you creating your pom descriptor for the jar file you are copying to the repository?

Comment: This is indeed the correct way. Or you can also do it at least manually by just adding a `ProjectName-1.0.pom` next to the Jar that contains your dependency artifact info.

Comment: @gil.fernandes sorry, you are right! I'll take a try!

Comment: @gil.fernandes Thank you! I also tried this command to deploy the jar in the local repo: `mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar -Durl=file:./maven-repository/ -DrepositoryId=maven-repository -DupdateReleaseInfo=true` and it works.

Comment: @davioooh: great, thank you for reporting back the exact command which worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your local jar as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/Name_Your_JAR.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Local works for you by doing above.If you want to pack this local jar in your fat jar then include following line in maven plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Define the pom.xml like dependency.

                  <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.myproject</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jarfile</systemPath>
                </dependency>

      Put the all the files in the folder
```

Comment: This seems to be a deprecated method: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies